Hide pdo credentials php connection
I wanted to know if there is any way to connect by PDO (in PHP) to the database and in this connection, not have to show either the host or the user or password by code, that is, some library or class where you can initialize these credentials once and then be able to access and make queries to the database without it being too confusing.

You can use .env file to store them and access them using getenv function.
